# Binary tree- SQL to Java representation

Tags: java, sql, tree, nested, binary-search-tree

I have this tree data structure representation in SQL and i want to display the data, with the correct relations of each node in Java so i can do any search algorithm on them.

SO,i thought that using left and right columns  i may transform a general tree into a binary tree so it would be more easier to apply more search algoritms on them.

Also, I want to be able to make different operations like add/remove root, nodes ,leafs.

[image]

I am a newbie in programming so here are my classes

```java
public class Node {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int leftId;
    private int rightId;
    private int deepth;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getLeftId() {
        return leftId;
    }

    public void setLeftId(int leftId) {
        this.leftId = leftId;
    }

    public int getRightId() {
        return rightId;
    }

    public void setRightId(int rightId) {
        this.rightId = rightId;
    }

    public int getDeepth() {
        return deepth;
    }

    public void setDeepth(int deepth) {
        this.deepth = deepth;
    }//con statement
            List<Node> nodes  = new ArrayList<>();
            while(rs.next())
            {Node nodes = new Node();
            nodes.setname( rs.getString("name"));
            //other 
            nodes.add(nodes);
            }
            return nodes;
}
public class tree{
//here i need help
}
```

Comment: So, what is the question? What did you try, where did it fail? What was the error or the undesired output?

Comment: I would recommend to use ordinary (not binary) tree for this structure, because some nodes have more than 2 children (Deputy Comissioner 1 for example).

Comment: I tried to assign values from database to coresponding left and right. But i don't succed. Reason? Beacuse i don't know what to assing for root and also leaf. See my answer

Comment: The URL for that image is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to assign values from database to coresponding left and right. But i don't succed. Reason? Beacuse i don't know what to assing for root and also leaf. I know that if i use values i can do like this (code for binary tree but inserting values from keyboard)

```
    <!-- language: Java-->
   class TreeNode<E> {
    protected E element;
    protected TreeNode<E> left;
    protected TreeNode<E> right;
    public TreeNode(E e) {
    element = e;
    }
    }// Create the root node
    TreeNode<Integer> root = new TreeNode<>(60);
    // Create the left child node
    root.left = new TreeNode<>(55);
    // Create the right child node
    root.right = new TreeNode<>(100);
-But i don't know how to get it from db in lists and assign them so i can use them
```

@Sasha Salauyou  i am trying to transform the ordinary tree from my db into an binary tree in java

Comment: any feedback is great received!